# Alternative to nesting links

Tags: html, dom, structure

I know that nesting  links ist illegal but what is the alternative?

Right now I am facing problem with links and I can not find the right answer.

```
<a href="/?id=2500,1111168" class="mehr-pfeil">
    <div class="date">10.07.2014</div>
    Öffentlichkeitsarbeit
</a>
```

The problem is following, I need to have **`<a href="#" class="mehr-pfeil">`** because of my collapse/expand effect but inside of this `<a>` should be real path to link. So when user comes to link it can expand and see details or he can directly go to the topic.

Comment: The question does not really say *why* you would need to nest links (and exactly how). This is probably a problem caused by the use of some library or template that uses `a` elements for collapsible lists, or something. Without seeing the real code and a description of the goal it is impossible to suhhest *how* it should be coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `<div class="mehr-pfeil">` instead of `<a href="#" class="mehr-pfeil">` and use some javascript logic with `onclick` to trigger the event that collapses/expands the div.

Comment: Could you please write me some example? It just need to be alternative for html's href="#"

Comment: What function or which plugin do you use to collapse/expand your container?

Comment: The href="#" is not needed at all. If you replace it with `div` like I said it will still work: http://jsfiddle.net/68RXP/1697/

Comment: I wont :) But unfortunately, it is not working because of something. Some of my colleagues obviously made some custom code and I am trying to figure out what is preventing TB to work as it should. Anyway, thank you very much! Ke Win!